# How to sort by project name in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, sorting, projects

I have one solution with 3 folders (Forms, Notices, Reports). In the Notice folder I have about 100 projects. The problem is, they are ordered by the creation date; while I would prefer that they were ordered by name.

I have seen that this does change, by sorting alphabetically, if I add a new project within the folder. But, once I close VS 2008 it resorts back to the creation date on reopening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=468874&wa=wsignin1.0

The only workaround I know is where you click a project name like you're going to rename it, but then just click off it onto another project node.  This re-sorts the list alphabetically, but it doesn't persist, you'll have to do it again when you reopen VS.